# JAVA Game - how does it work?

Tags: java

(I'm new to Java (or programming in general) and am trying to figure out how this game works.
I know that the game field is divided in 3 areas: color picker area, score area and the draw area. But which variable determine which ranges in which way?
 - What are the relative and absolute size components of the color picker area and game control area? What does it do?
 - Why did the programmer divided the TILE_SIZE just to multiply it again?
 - How and for what do they initialize the 2D array myTiles in public static void initColorGame() method?)

Comment: That's alot of questions, is there anything you did understand about the code?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile due to the part at the end that says `enter code here`. Also, your class says it implements `MouseListener`, but it doesn't have implementations for any of the `MouseListener` methods.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
@RossDrew : No, I don't get how it works at all. I actually have more questions, but that are what I want to know most.
@ Rusty: The whole program was long, so I just left the parts with the questions.

Comment: Lol the bit with the multiplication then division with TILE_SIZE is amusing.

Comment: @PeterMichealLacey-Bordeaux: How so?

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But which variable determine which ranges in which way?

I don't really understand what you're asking here.

---

> What are the relative and absolute size components of the color picker area and game control area? What does it do?

Relative size? Relative to what? I don't understand what "it" is when you ask "What does it do?"

The code looks like it creates a layout like this:
[image]

There seems to be padding of 5 pixels around each element.

I don't feel like I can tell you exact numbers because layout tends to be based on *preferred sizes*. Many times, the Swing layout managers will take your height/width values as suggestions to allow graceful resizing. The easiest way to tell is to run the program.

---

> Why did the programmer divided the TILE_SIZE just to multiply it again?

If `width - 10` is not divisible by `TILE_SIZE`, the divide -> multiply process will round the value down to a value that *is* divisible by `TILE_SIZE`. Here's some code to prove that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 40;
    int divisor = 5;
    int result = (value / divisor) * divisor;
    System.out.println("Exact: " + result); // outputs 40

    value = 43;
    result = (value / divisor) * divisor;
    System.out.println("Inexact: " + result); // outputs 40
}
```

Personally, I think this is hackish and hard to read. I prefer finding the excess using the mod operator:

```
int excess = (width - 10) % TILE_SIZE;
drawWidth = (width - 10) - excess;
```

---

> How and for what do they initialize the 2D array myTiles in public static void initColorGame() method?

Let's look at the code, bit by bit:

```
myTiles[x][y] = (int)(Math.random()*colors.length);
```

`Math.random()` generates a double that is randomly distributed between 0.0 and 1.0 (you can read the specifics in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)).

`colors.length` is the number of color choices that are possible.

By multiplying them together, we get a random number in the range of possible color indexes. The only problem is that the result is upcasted to a double. By casting back to an `int`, the decimal portion is removed and we have a randomly generated index for the `colors` array. I prefer using `Math.round()` because I think it's more semantically correct and easier to read, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm not used to English. I think I understand it more now. Thank you for answering.

Comment: No apology needed; you did nothing wrong. I just needed more clarification. Glad to help.